# Get instant XML updates from source URL

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, reactjs

I need to get regular updates from an XML file. The XML file is available over a URL like this (example) http://www.bbc.co.uk/sitemap.xml.

This file gets updated frequently but on irregular intervals. As soon as there is an update to the file I want to be able to retrieve the data from the file, processes it and display the latest data to the end user in html.

I should only processes the xml if there is an update to it otherwise it will be too slow.

What is the best approach for this? Which frontend framework/library should I use? Should I make this http call from frontend or backend (java)?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Java Watch Service API:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html